# Storyboard - Elements isn't exist in all screen sizes (XCode 6)

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

I am newbie. I design UI at screen that w = Compact and h = Regular.
 This is appearance of the views :
[image]

But if I change screen size. The UI elements is vanish. 
For example, I change to w = Any. h = Regular
[image]

**How to solve this problem ?**

Comment: Did you set Auto Layout constraints for the elements?

Comment: In the new versions of Xcode you can organize the elements just by Auto Layout constraints and you don't need that old w and h settings. Try that four little buttons in the lower right corner of IB to align UI controls and set constraints between them. For example to align them center use the first one from left and to set dynamic weight and height use the second one. Apple recommends this way to organize controls because you can make universal apps easily. For more info read Apple documentations about using Auto Layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you didn't set any constraints to layout....so without any constraints its not visible for all size classes...and its visible only for the size class where you actually created the UI...but that doesn't means that it not visible to your simulator or device...but it displays  ui as it is...

So, check in document outline where you can find hierarchy of the objects ...you actually see that objects are hidden for size classes except one in which you actually created the layout....so, give the constraints to objects and you can see the layout in all size classes..